# Create dictionaries of objects in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've created a dict of objects (creditcards):

```
class CreditCard:

    def __init__(self,number,expire_date_month,expire_date_year,CVC):
        self.number=number
        self.expire_date_month=expire_date_month
        self.expire_date_year=expire_date_year
        self.CVC=CVC

credit_cards={CreditCard('1000000000000000','3','2011','111'):'VISA'}
credit_cards_frozen=frozenset({CreditCard('1000000000000000','3','2011','111'):'VISA'})
```

but I have an error while executing these commands:

```
print credit_cards['VISA'] #KeyError: 'VISA'
print credit_cards_frozen['VISA'] #TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not subscriptable
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What is your actual intention when writing `credit_cards['VISA']`, getting the `CreditCard('1000000000000000','3','2011','111')` object or all `CreditCard` objects of type `VISA`?

Comment: `frozenset()`  does not accept `dict`s as arguments, but set and sequence-like object, i.e. you have to call `frozenset(adict.items()), but then you cannot use it like a dict anymore. Why do you need frozen version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there are two things that are wrong with your code.

- If you want the CreditCard object to be retrieved by its associated string ('VISA' in this case), you should make the string the key and the object the value and not the other way around. Your `dict` should look like this,

  `credit_cards={'VISA':CreditCard('1000000000000000','3','2011','111')}`

  If there are multiple objects for the same string, the value can be a `list` of those objects.
- `frozenset` is not a `dict`. It does not store (key, value) paired data. Creating a `frozenset` from a `dict` just creates a set with all the keys of the dict. Why do you need it anyway?